# typeset -f does not output the real definition. Can it be detected/fixed?

Tags: bash

I spent the better part of yesterday pulling my hair out to discover the bug is in Bash.

```
outer () 
{ 
    function inner () 
    { 
        cat <<_EOS
foo
_EOS
    }
    inner
}
```

will be displayed by `typeset -f outer` as:

```
outer () 
{ 
    function inner () 
    { 
        cat <<_EOS
    }
foo
_EOS
    inner
}
```

which is clearly not the same. In CygWin (bash 4.4.12) the output is wrong in a different way:

```
outer ()
{
    function inner ()
    {
        cat
    } <<_EOS
foo
_EOS

    inner
}
```

The bug has been fixed in newer versions of Bash.

I use this for `env_parallel`. `env_parallel` depends on the output from `typeset -f` to be correct.

This is a corner case bug, so I really do not want `env_parallel` to spit out a warning unless there is a real risk it will affect the result. On the other hand, I would like a warning if there is a real risk, because I really do not want users to be as frustrated as I was yesterday.

Can it be detected reliably if the bug is present in the output of `typeset -f`?
Can it be corrected without writing a bash parser?

Comment: Would you mind linking to the bug report?

Comment: @bishop I do not know if there is a report. The problem is gone in the newest version in git.

Answer (score 11):

You can check whether some code is syntactically valid with:

```
if bash -O extglob -n < some-code 2> /dev/null; then
  echo that seems valid
fi
```

However note that syntax can be affected by aliases, the locale (LC_CTYPE category) and in bash the `extglob` option.

For instance, a piece of code could be valid with `extglob` but not without (like `echo @(x)`), generally not the other way round, so it's better to check the syntax with `extglob` on.

A piece of code could be valid in one locale and not another (`$'\xe9=(x)'` would be valid in the `fr_FR.iso88591` locale but not in a UTF-8 locale or the C locale), as what character is valid in a variable name (and also as token delimiter!) depends on the locale (for that reason, it's also generally dangerous to feed the output of `typeset -f` to another bash invocation which is not of the same version or not running in the same locale on the same system).

```
alias forever='while true; do'
forever echo test; done
```

Would be reported as invalid by `bash -n`, but not by `bash -O expand_aliases`, because as soon as the `alias` command is run, the second line becomes valid. Not a problem here when checking the syntax of the output of `typeset -f` though.

Here, you could use that to detect the syntax errors caused by that or other bug, but it would not be foolproof because of the considerations mentioned above, but also because that bug could still generate valid code by accident.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable solution: It does not have to be a 100% solution. If I can just issue a warning when it looks problematic, then it is good-enough.